# using a function in custom javascript file in drupal

Tags: javascript

i made a module that creates a block and using #attached i added my custom .js file to block content, without Drupal.behaviors and function($) things my code works like a clock in another page (outside of Drupal) but in Drupal, i have no idea how to add a function in .js file
here are my codes:

```
(function($){
    Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    attach:function(context, settings) {
                function show_more(count){
                var counter = count;
                var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest;
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML =xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("POST","some_page.php",true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-        urlencoded");
               xmlhttp.send("counter="+encodeURIComponent(counter)+"&id="+encodeURIComponent(id    ));
            $("#div_id").fadeToggle(2000);
               }
        }
    }
       })(JQuery);
```

i am new to drupal and Jquery please help me
and please tell me how can i call show_more function in my content
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include a JS file by theme or drupal_add_js($data = NULL, $options = NULL) function. Simply write your functions into file and use it simply. This file and its function will be available on your whole website pages.